# wxPython background image disturbance

Tags: background, wxpython, frame

wxPython background code is distrubing other sizers. How do I fix it so that it won't influence other objects in the frame?

```
backgroundfile = wx.Image(backgroundfilepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, backgroundfile, (0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`wx.StaticBitmap` is a distinct widget, and the behavior of overlapping sibling widgets is undefined in wx. A better approach would be to bind a handler for the parent's `EVT_PAINT` event and draw the background bitmap in that handler.

Comment: hey, i have succeed to bind EVT_PAINT but not really understood what to do after i bind it, how do i draw the background bitmap in that handler?

Comment: Create a `wx.PaintDC` and use its `DrawBitmap` method.  See the `wx.DC` docs for more options and details about drawing to a window, and also several samples in the demo that do custom drawing.